# using JSON-Framework to prepare a json object to post via HTTP Request Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, post, httpwebrequest

I am successfully using the json-framework to do GET HttpRequests. Does anyone have code to prepare a json object and do a POST HTTP Request? If so, can you please share some sample objective-c code. Thanks

Comment: Hi Zap, did you figure this one out? Am looking to do the same thing but cant find an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [open source project](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) hosted at google code.

**Description:**

This framework implements a strict JSON parser and generator in Objective-C.

Download the framework, embed it in your application, and import the JSON.h header. You're now ready to make your application speak JSON. The framework adds categories to existing Objective-C objects for a super-simple interface, and provides classes with more flexible APIs for added control.

Answer (score 1):

Try `TwitterHelper.m` in Stanford's [CS 193P](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php) "[Presence3Files.zip](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/downloads/Presence3Files.zip)" package.

I would post the code directly but am unsure if that is cool, license-wise.

Answer (score 0):

USe following code for making a Post Request using JSON Data Object.

```
   self.responseData=[NSMutableData data];

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.iworklab.com/myProject/index.php"];

   NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"method\":\"changePassword\",\"customer_id\":\"%@\",\"old_password\":\"%@\",\"new_password\":\"%@\",\"con_password\":\"%@\"}",customerID,oldPasswordText.text,newPasswordText.text,confirmPasswordText.text];

   jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&json_data=%@",jsonRequest];

   NSData *json_data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request setHTTPBody: json_data];

   [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [json_data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
   [request setHTTPBody:[[jsonRequest stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
                      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                      allowLossyConversion:YES]];

    passwordConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```